# Cutting doorway into load bearing wall above empty room

Tags: walls, construction, load-bearing, door-frame

I opened up a load bearing wall in the 2nd floor to add a doorway and found strange framing and studs. The wall is right above where the opening for the room is shown in this picture where the ceiling comes down slightly:[image: 1st floor beneath the wall I want to add doorway too]

I worry the double layer of baseboards and the weird studs are somehow related to supporting the 2nd floor since there is no wall beneath it. Is it safe to put in a doorway or will taking out the baseboard on the floor running between the studs and moving this double stud going to weaken the 2nd story floor and this wall too much?
[image: side view where you can see weird studs and extra boards]

[image: wide view of the open wall, strange studs and you can see the raised layer of baseplate 2x4s running on either side of the stud bases]

Comment: I wouldn't worry too much on the floor below, but you need to check the roof or upper floor framing to see whether these studs carry the load to the second-floor framing, and what is the structural element supporting the second floor between the first-floor opening now (beneath the studs shown in the photos).

Comment: What is directly above the double vertical studs. I suspect the studs connect into a beam upstairs or in the attic.

Comment: When you say, “where the ceiling comes down slightly” is that a beam over the opening?

Comment: @LeeSam I have no idea what's inside that part of the ceiling where the new room starts (where it comes down slightly like 8 inches) but I would assume there are beams in there to redistribute the load to the walls on either side of it

Comment: Is the beam on the 1st floor opening clad in sheetrock or wood that sheen on the paint from the light shows little to no texture.

Comment: @davidmoritz definitely sheetrock and drywall. No idea what's inside it though

Comment: If the box is decorative, then the twin-stud is not load bearing. If it's structural, it might be. I suspect the kitchen joists rest on it, which makes it structural. Could it be a beam placed there during an earlier reno, replacing a wall there? Confirm by skimming a flashlight along the ceiling, which may reveal the joist direction. Also take a picture in the attic right above the twin studs. Move insulation out of the way so we can see all of the framing.